# ios app developed in 3.5-inch when changed to 4-inch the position of button is wrong after added the @2x launch image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My app was designed in 3.5-inch, but after I added the launch image the position of buttons was wrong when running on 4-inch device, so I built a new .xib in 4-inch, and copy the layout from 3.5-inch and adjust buttons. But it didn't work, I just wonder how can I connect the new .xib with the code in .h wrote for the 3.5-inch .xib file. Thank you very much!

Comment: you have to manage there control frame bcz the hight of view has been change. so you have two choice use Auto-layout for this and you can also check with it's 4 inch or 3.5 inc and then crate separated story-board or xib for both

Comment: yes, I had created separated xib for both, how can I use the .h wrote for both?

Comment: if you are craete separated xib then from xib-->inspector there are open size interface you can set 4 or 3.5 and set accordingly your control

Comment: now, I have myapp.m, myapp.h, myapp3.5_inch.xib and myapp4_inch.xib but the buttons in myapp4_inch.xib were not conneted with myapp.h, how can I do this?

Comment: sorry about that, also thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to manage there control frame Because this view's has been change for 3.5 and 4 inc screen. You have two choice for it One is Using Aunt-Layout and other one is using separated `story-board` or `Xib` for each `View-controller`.

if you are using `story-board` or `Xib` for each `View-controller`. then you can set it's Like Bellow screen Shot:-

[image]

Here you can set it's size for 3.5 xib set 3.5 and 4 for 4 inc full screen.

and you can set it's sub Class for this view like bellow screenshot:-

[image]

if you are using `xib` not `storyboard` then you just need to set class no need for setting identity. Hope now you getting me and you issue will solved.

**NOTE**
Also check that into view controller are you using navigation Bar then put control with navigation in xib so you set actually position for control